# “Unable to locate package” errors for all software

Tags: command-line

I try to install programs with `apt-get install` but always it shows same error: `unable to locate package`. For example I try to install the `language-support-fonts-fa`
; here's what happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package language-support-fonts-fa
```

Comment: You try to install in an old unsupported Ubuntu release. The question is therefore considered as off topic. To still be able to install see http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is normal as long as `language-support-fonts-fa` is not in your current repositories.

To check if a package is in the repositories, use the following command:

```
apt-cache search <package_name>
```

In this case, you can download and install manually `language-support-fonts-fa` package from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/language-support-fonts-fa/download

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your example it's likely that you're missing the PPA you need to install that package. The best way to add a PPA is to follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding_Launchpad_PPA_Repositories). But to summarize, you would do something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-langpack
```

Now, at this point you need to refresh the package indexes on your machine:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After this you should be able to add the package you want.

This is a bit different than the other answer in that package dependencies will be installed and that future package updates will be noticed and installed each time you do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.